# How to change background image on hover and text color CSS MVC 5

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, hover, mousehover

Here is my div,

```
<div >
                    <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Employees")">
                            <img src="~/AppFiles/Images/Tile.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail border border-success">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <p>@Resource.Employee</p>
                                <p>@ViewBag.EmpCount</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

when I hover on div I want to change the `src` of the `img` to `'~/AppFiles/Images/HoverTile.png'`, and in `class="caption"` I want the color of text to change to `white`

Hopes for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your css file:

```
.thumbnail:hover {
 // Write everything you want to happen after hover


}
```

same for 'caption' class

```
 .caption:hover {
 color:white;
 }
```

If you wanna do it with javascript and change the src:

```
<img id="my-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" 
onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" />

function hover(element) {
element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}

function unhover(element) {
element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
}
```

Comment: it seems like helpful but how would i change img url in thumbnail hover any idea ?

Comment: If you want to change the background photo you can add to the thmbnail:hover class : background-image: url('YourPath')

Comment: i want to change <img src =''"> inside <a href >

Comment: You can't do it with only html and css.

The only way of doing it with hover is the way I told you

Comment: You can do it with javascript , I will edit my answer. if my answer was useful please care to mark it

Comment: thanks its working but i have little issue there it is working on upper part of image i check it thanks